# Unable to update nodes position using d3 force and Svelte

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svelte

I'm trying to create a simple network using D3 force and Svelte.

The network position should depend on the container dimensions computed using `bind:clientWidth` and `bind:clientHeight`.
I mean that if the network container has width=200, height=300, then the network center should be x=100, y=150.

The code that creates the graph is this:

```html
  export let width;
  export let height;

  let svg;
  let simulation;
  let zoomTransform = zoomIdentity;
  let links = $network.links.map(d => cloneDeep(d));
  let nodes = $network.nodes.map(d => cloneDeep(d));

  simulation = forceSimulation(nodes)
    .force(
      "link",
      forceLink(
        links.map(l => {
          return {
            ...l,
            source: nodes.find(n => n.id === l.source),
            target: nodes.find(n => n.id === l.source)
          };
        })
      )
    )
    .force(
      "collision",
      forceCollide()
        .strength(0.2)
        .radius(120)
        .iterations(1)
    )
    .force("charge", forceManyBody().strength(0))
    .force("center", forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
    .on("tick", simulationUpdate);
  // .stop()
  // .tick(100)

  function simulationUpdate() {
    simulation.tick();
    nodes = nodes.map(n => cloneDeep(n));
    links = links.map(l => cloneDeep(l));
  }

  $: {
    simulation
      .force("center")
      .x(width / 2)
      .y(height / 2);
  }
</script>

<svg bind:this={svg} viewBox={`${0} ${0} ${width} ${height}`} {width} {height}>
    {#if simulation}
      <g>
        {#each links as link}
          <Link {link} {nodes} />
        {/each}
      </g>
    {:else}
      null
    {/if}

    {#if simulation}
      <g>
        {#each nodes as node}
            <Node {node} x={node.x} y={node.y} />
        {/each}
      </g>
    {:else}
      null
    {/if}
</svg>
```

It's very simple: `width` and `height` are props.
It create some local stores and updated them with new data.
Since that `width` and `height` are dynamic, I compute the `forceCenter` force in a reactive block.

Then, to draw the nodes, I use a `Node` component with prop `nodes`, `x`, `y`. I kwnow that I can use only `nodes` or only `x,y` but it was a test. The problem is that the nodes position never changes even if `width` and `height` change.

So if you change the window size, the graph is not recomputed but it should. Why?

[HERE a complete working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-booth-8ky619?file=/App.svelte)

Thank you!

Comment: You might want to `stop()` the simulation in `onDestroy` if this component can be unmounted again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the issues is that you replace the `nodes`/`links` references. This entails that the simulation happens on objects that you no longer have any reference to, while you render a different set of objects, which after the first tick will never change again.

One approach would be to add a separate object/s that are used for updating the DOM generated by Svelte.

e.g.

```js
  let links = $network.links.map(d => cloneDeep(d));
  let nodes = $network.nodes.map(d => cloneDeep(d));
  // Initial render state
  let render = {
    links,
    nodes,
  }

  // ...

  function simulationUpdate() {
    // (No need to call tick, a tick has already happened here)
    render = {
      nodes: nodes.map(d => cloneDeep(d)),
      links: links.map(d => cloneDeep(d)),
    };
  }
```

Adjust the `each` loops. You also need to make the links loop keyed, or  adjust the `Link` component code to make `sourceNode`/`targetNode` reactive instead of `const`:

```html
{#each render.links as link (link)}
...
{#each render.nodes as node}
```

(Using the `link` itself as key causes a re-render of all elements because the links are cloned, so none of the objects are identical.)

Also, you might need to call `restart` when the center changes to make sure it applies correctly:

```js
  $: {
    simulation
      .force("center")
      .x(width / 2)
      .y(height / 2);
    simulation.restart();
  }
```

---

Alternatively to having separate objects for rendering, you can use the `{#key}` feature to make the DOM re-render (for large graphs this may have a negative impact). You only need some variable to change and use that as trigger:

```js
  let renderKey = false;
  // ...
  function simulationUpdate() {
    renderKey = !renderKey;
  }
```

```html
    {#if simulation}
      {#key renderKey}
        <g>
          {#each links as link}
            <Link {link} {nodes} />
          {/each}
        </g>
        <g>
          {#each nodes as node}
              <Node {node} x={node.x} y={node.y} />
          {/each}
        </g>
      {/key}
    {/if}
```

Comment: Thank you.
In your example the Node component use as `x` and `y` the `x, y` props and not `x, y` fields inside `node`.
I prefer to pass to the component only the `node` prop. In that case it doesn't work, nodes are not in the right position. Why?

Comment: @whitecircle Probably another case of the component not re-rendering. Have you tried to make the `each` for `nodes` keyed on `node`?

Comment: Oh, thanks! I solved as you suggested